# Assign a value to a property of a class within a class

Tags: c#, class, oop

I have the following code

```
class TopClass
{
    public string ClsProp1 { get; set; }
    public string ClsProp2 { get; set; }

    public SubClass ClsProp3 { get; set; }
}

class SubClass
{
    public string SCProp1 { get; set; }
    public string SCProp2 { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Test.TopClass TCN = new Test.TopClass();

        TCN.ClsProp1 = "TCProp1--string value";
        TCN.ClsProp2 = "TCProp2--string value";
        TCN.ClsProp3.SCProp1 = "SCProp1--string value";
        TCN.ClsProp3.SCProp2 = "SCProp2--string value";

    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to instantiate the TCN.ClsProp3.ScProp1 and TCN.ClsProp3.ScProp2 values.  I keep getting the "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Test.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error message.  Forgive my ignorance, I'm really trying to learn OOP from scratch.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to initialize the `ClsProp3` object before you can use it.

```
TCN.ClsProp3 = new SubClass();
```

You could also initialize it in the `TopClass` constructor like this:

```
class TopClass
{
    public TopClass()
    {
        ClsProp3 = new SubClass();
    }
    public string ClsProp1 { get; set; }
    public string ClsProp2 { get; set; }

    public SubClass ClsProp3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Doh.. I can't believe it was that simple.  I was pretty sure I had that in my code.  thank you for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

When learning, it's better to pick a good domain. `TopClass` with `ClsPropX` do not make for a nice learning experience.

As for your original question, launch the debugger and see what the `ClsProp3` equals to. And bear in mind that it's impossible to assign anything to "nothingness", which is `null` in C# parlance.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand your comment, but thank you for taking the time to comment anyway.